# Getting the header of the two matching criterias, for multiple tables

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Hoping you can help me out.
I have a total of three tables here. I've been trying to figure out a formula that will give me the header (the names) of the two criteria specified in H1 and H2. I was able to get the result I want, but for the first table only (Hailey).

The problem is to find out who among the three teachers handled the "subject" within the specified month as well.

Also, I couldn't figure out how to get all the results if ever there are two names that match the criteria. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: tbh, this is just bad data design for a worksheet. It would be infinitely easier if everything was in three columns; e.g. *month, subject, name*. I also imagine that you actually have more than three names which complicates things further. If you pursue this data design then use Power Query (aka SQL) to join the data ranges. If you put everything into the three columns as I mentioned, you could retrieve individual tables as above for reporting and be able to easily retrieve the data you're asking for.

Comment: I understand what you all are saying. However, there’s a reason why the tables are placed ike that. Each of those people has their own deck (term i used for the set of range containing different tables and information for one teacher) in the same worksheet. So each table is just part of a bigger range. I appreciate all your tips and comments. I placed those tables that way so it can be easier to capture in photo. They are not originally arranged like that, but if you can help me figure out a formula that can get the result i want, I believe it should also work on the original sheet. Thanks

Comment: I was also able to come up with s workaround for this. I used the query formula to merge the tables into a separate sheet as well as make an index match like function but using query as well. However, im still trying to get the same result in a way that i dont have to create another sheet.

Comment: Lovely, can you post your answer? : ) @christine

Answer (score 1):

as Jeeped said above this is essentially bad database/table methodology but it is not hard to fix, what you need to do is create three columns one for the name, subject and month.

Then what you can do is just run a simple SQL/Google Query to find out who is doing what.

I've created a template based of your screenshot above but with three columns, have a play around and if you redesign your spreadsheet just let us know and we can help you to design a query for your issue.

use the drop downs to get your desired query, if you select name & month you get that range, if you select a month you get all names for that month.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yERKtQocnVqopqh6CCn6Rdj143bYyr_IjSDnzCLSm_8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I completely agree although you have provided some depth.

Comment: I understand what you all are saying. However, there’s a reason why the tables are placed ike that. Each of those people has their own deck (term i used for the set of range containing different tables and information for one teacher) in the same worksheet. So each table is just part of a bigger range. I appreciate all your tips and comments. I placed those tables that way so it can be easier to capture in photo. They are not originally arranged like that, but if you can help me figure out a formula that can get the result i want, I believe it should also work on the original sheet. Thanks